# C# database update

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm stuck on a little problem concerning database.

Once a month I get a XML file with customer information (Name, address, city,etc.). My primary key is a customer number which is provided in the XML file.

I have no trouble inserting the information in the database;

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [customer_info] 
   (customer_nr, firstname, lastname, address_1, address_2, address_3.......)");
//some code
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now, I would like to update my table or just fill it with new information. How can I achieve this?

I've tried using `TableAdapter` but it does not work.

And I'm only permitted to add one XML because I can only have one `customer_nr` as primary key.

So basically how do I update or fill my table with new information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdaTheDev has indeed given the good suggestion.

But in case, you must insert/update from .NET code then you can

1. Create a stored procedure that will handle insert/update i.e. instead of using a direct insert query as command text, you make a call to stored proc. The SP will check if row exists or not and then update (or insert).
2. User TableAdapter - but this would be tedious. First you have to setup both insert & update commands. Then you have to query the database to get the existing customer numbers and then update the corresponding rows in the datatable making the Rowstate as Updated. I would rather not go this way.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to bulk insert the data into a new staging table in the database (you could use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) for this for optimal insert speed). Once it's in there, you could then index the customer_nr field and then run 2 statements:

```
-- UPDATE existing customers
UPDATE ci
SET ci.firstname = s.firstname,
    ci.lastname = s.lastname, 
    ... etc
FROM StagingTable s
    INNER JOIN Customer_Info ci ON s.customer_nr = ci.customer_nr

-- INSERT new customers
INSERT Customer_Info (customer_nr, firstname, lastname, ....)
SELECT s.customer_nr, s.firstname, s.lastname, ....
FROM StagingTable s
    LEFT JOIN Customer_Info ci ON s.customer_nr = ci.customer_nr
WHERE ci.customer_nr IS NULL
```

Finally, drop your staging table.

Alternatively, instead of the 2 statements, you could just use the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement if you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, which allows you to do INSERTs and UPDATEs via a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly - if the customer already exists you want to update their information, and if they don't already exist you want to insert a new row.

I have a lot of problems with hard-coded SQL commands in your code, so I would firstly be very tempted to refactor what you have done.  However, to achieve what you want, you will need to execute a `SELECT` on the primary key, if it returns any results you should execute an `UPDATE` else you should execute an `INSERT`.

It would be best to do this in something like a `Stored Procedure` - you can pass the information to the stored procedure at then it can make a decision on whether to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` - this would also reduce the overhead of making several calls for your code to the database (A stored procedure would be much quicker)